# Xamarin Forms: Issue with showing a PDF files using Webview

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, webview

I am using a custom renderer for showing a pdf file on my app.

Below are my renderer codes:

**Main Project:**

```
public class PdfWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Uri",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(PdfWebView),
    defaultValue: default(string));
    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Android:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PdfWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace Projectname.Droid.Renderer
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                var customWebView = Element as PdfWebView;
                Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;

                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url={0}", customWebView.Uri.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml and Xaml.cs:**

```
<local:PdfWebView 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    x:Name="pdf_Webview"/>
    
pdf_Webview.Uri = pdfurl;
```

But when I run the app on the android platform getting the below exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

No Renderers are using on the ios part and pdf is working fine on there. What is the actual issue on the android part?

Comment: which line is throwing the exception?  Is `customWebView` null?

Comment: @Jason The solution on the below thread is working. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/383713/xamarin-forms-issue-with-showing-a-pdf-files-using.html

Comment: @Jason But the PDF file is continuously loading, please watch the below video. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bbr9LTX39AY9CYU6ddvncYs2AtZxY-IS/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made below modifications on the renderer. Got this solution from my own [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/383713/xamarin-forms-issue-with-showing-a-pdf-files-using.html).

```
public class MyWebViewRenderer  : WebViewRenderer
{
    PdfWebView customWebView;
    public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            customWebView = Element as PdfWebView;
            Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            if (customWebView.Uri != null)
            {
                Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url={0}", customWebView.Uri.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (customWebView.Uri != null && !Control.Url.Contains(customWebView.Uri))
        {
            Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url={0}", customWebView.Uri.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```